# Find an especific color coordenates on an image

Tags: bash, imagemagick

I would like to find the coordinates of the first appearance of a certain color, for example green, on an image so can be used in a bash script.

I've been trying to use Imagemagick but can't find a way to solve the problem.

Can this be done with Imagemagick or should I use anything else?

Comment: The code that I sent you does that. Get the first element of the yArr after the sort. That will be the top left corner of the bounding box for that region of your color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way in ImageMagick using sparse-color: (provided the image is fully opaque). Sparse-color will read out the x,y coordinates and color of all fully opaque pixels. Then you can use unix tools to get the first one.

Create red and blue image:

```
convert -size 10x10 xc:red xc:blue -append x.png
```

Find first rgb(0,0,255) i.e. blue colored pixel

```
convert x.png sparse-color: | tr " " "\n" | grep "srgb(0,0,255)" | head -n 1
```

Result

```
0,10,srgb(0,0,255)
```

Similar results can be achieved using txt: in place of sparse-color. But the unix commands for filtering would be a bit different.